# What is "normal" Excel behavior of macro called by Application.OnTime during cell edit?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA beginner trying to determine the "normal" behavior of excel during a timed call to a macro using `Application.OnTime`.  In my code (below) I am calling `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` but I think this question may be relevant to the timed call to any macro.  As a newbie, I want to understand the behavior and limits of VBA so that I can determine if VBA is the right tool or if I should use another solution in certain cases (perhaps python / openpyxl).

My set up:  I am using Microsoft Excel 365 (annual subscription) and the Account page says I am using Version 2006 (Build 13001.20384 Click-to-Run). I have a single workbook containing a single Sheet1 which contains the formulas to import stock data using the built in feature under the Excel Data tab.  I have several rows (one stock per row) of columnar data corresponding to the stock fields such as ticker symbol, price, etc.

To automatically refresh the data, I borrowed & modified code to refresh the data every minute.  The code works fine.  The "issue" I have is that between refreshes, if I start editing any cell on the sheet and continue to do so during the time when the next automatic call to the refresh should occur, it indefinitely delays the execution of said call until the moment I complete (or cancel) the cell edit.  When it does the refresh upon my edit completion that refresh does seem to work correctly.

If I start a cell edit and do not complete it for several minutes then only a single refresh occurs when I complete (or cancel) the edit, even though several intervals may have passed (it does not makeup/catchup the missed/delayed calls).

This behavior is OK with me in this application, but I would like to understand if this is considered "normal" behavior, and if I should expect it to always behave this way. Perhaps this question extends beyond a refresh call but also to any timed call to any macro that may be delayed as a result of a cell edit in progress.

Here is my code.

This is in a file called VBA-Test-02-StockData.xlsm under ThisWorkbook (Code):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    'ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    Application.Speech.Speak ("Activating stock workbook")
    Call AutoRefresh
End Sub
```

This is in the same xlsm file under Module1 (Code):

```
Sub RefreshStockData()
    Application.Speech.Speak ("Refreshing stock data")
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
Sub AutoRefresh()
    Call RefreshStockData
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "AutoRefresh"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's by design. Excel won't run VBA code while in Edit mode.

Comment: A lot of things will not work when in Edit mode. Press F2 and have a look at the icons in the ribbon. Most of them will be greyed out.